# Computing ratio of two sums

Tags: numerical-methods, power-series, rational-functions, analytic-continuation

I'm interested in computing

$$ f(s) := \frac{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n s^n } { \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n s^n } $$

for some given $s \in \mathbb{C}$, where the power series in the numerator and denominator diverge at $s$ but $f(s)$ still converges at $s$.  Or, roughly speaking, the infinities for $a_n$ and $b_n$ cancel at $s$.

Formally speaking, if we take

$$ f_N(s) := \frac{ \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n s^n } { \sum_{n=0}^{N} b_n s^n } $$

to be some sort of partial approximation, then

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} f_N(s) = f(s)$$

and I'm interested in computing, say $f_{128}(s)$ as a numerical approximation of $f(s)$.

If I naively sum the numerator and denominator to some given number of terms I lose a lot of precision, as the very large terms swamp the smaller terms.  Is there another way to compute $f(s)$ that would do a better job of preserving precision?  I expect the ratio of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ to be fairly well behaved, even if $a_n, b_n$ individually blow up.

Comment: 1. I don't think I understand the problem.  I don't understand what you mean by losing a lot of precision: if the very large terms swamp the smaller terms, then presumably that means the smaller terms have very little effect on the value of the numerator or denominator, so I don't understand what it would have much effect on the ratio.  2. Are $a_n,b_n$ all positive?  Is it that they can be negative and you're worried about a large positive term cancelling a large negative term?

Comment: To clarify, you want an approximated function of $f_N(s)$ to evaluate at any $s$, small or big?

Comment: @D.W. for large enough $n$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ can be so large that they run the risk of overflow, even for doubles.  Even if they don't overflow, the sums in the numerator and denominator might overflow.  I think there's also something going on like subnormals, but for very large numbers, but I'm not knowledgable about how floating point handles very very large numbers.  I was hoping to find an expression for $f_N(s)$ in terms of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ since that's fairly well behaved.

Comment: Yes, a Cesaro-Stolz theorem exists and handles the case of quotients of diverging series.

Comment: @TonyMathew I know a priori a radius of convergence for $f(s)$, and I want to evaluate $f_N(s)$ for $s$ within that radius of convergence.